# Using axios instance with "baseURL" results in faulty requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to create a wrapper for `axios`, so I can always use the same configuration.

The following works as expected:

```
function getAxiosInstance() {
  const config = {
    timeout: 3000,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  return axios.create(config);
}

getAxiosInstance().get('/foo');
```

However, just adding `baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/'` to the configuration (i.e. `config`) results in two weird requests: The first [without any request method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srXzl.png) and the second one [has a method of type `OPTIONS`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exLZd.png).

I tried omitting the domain and port (`/api/`) which surprisingly worked, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm using the latest version of axios (0.21.0) although I tried with an earlier one as well.

Comment: This is normal behaviour for browsers. It is a CORS issue

Comment: Install a CORS extension from your browser extension store

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot! @ManosKounelakis

Comment: Sure no problem !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was indeed a (vaguely indicated) CORS config I had to change on the backend.